# Quantum Computing, and if a Q-bit can be entangled and in superposition at the same time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, superposition

I was wondering if a Q-bits can be in both entangled and in superposition at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest example, the Bell singlet $\vert +\rangle \vert -\rangle - \vert -\rangle\vert +\rangle$, is entangled and in a superposition.

Of course, one must remember that *superposition* is a basis-dependent concept, i.e. the state $\vert +\rangle_z +\vert -\rangle_z$ is in a superposition of states with spin along $\hat z$, but is an eigenstate of $\sigma_x$ and thus not in a superposition of states of spin along $\hat x$.

In fact, if a state is separable and thus not entangled, it would be of the form $\vert a\rangle \vert b\rangle$ in *some* basis, and thus not be in a superposition in a basis of eigenstate of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$, where $\hat A\vert a\rangle = a\vert a\rangle$ and $\hat B\vert b\rangle = b\vert b\rangle$.